# How to convert a squence task in loop to parallel?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have an executable file `my_exe` that provides a float random number. The output of the same iteration will display in the same line with tab \t and the next iters will be in the new line

The output will be

```
0.6 0.7 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.4
...
```

Currently, I used a sequence way (loop) to do it. How can I speed up it by running it in parallel way?

```
for i in {1..10}; do
   printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe)
done > out.txt
```

Comment: How long does `my_exe` take to run? I'm just wondering if you'd get any speed benefit at all from parallelizing.

Comment: try `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(./my_exe &) $(./my_exe &) $(./my_exe &)` or `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(./my_exe) & $(./my_exe) & $(./my_exe) &` . `&` runs a cmd in the background.   Good luck.

Comment: If you're looking for wider scale parallelization, you could consider something like GNU parallel. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ It's designed to do exactly what you want, possibly over multiple machines.

Comment: But whether you use GNU parallel or @shellter's solution, you'll have to manually worry about reordering the output, if order matters. For example, you could output each instance to `output.<i>` and then concatenate them in the right order, padding `<i>` with enough zeroes so that `output.*` expands to all the files in the right order.

Comment: @joanis , Yes I had thought about order too, not sure what the rules between `printf` and `$(float_producing_program) x3` are ; will outputs be assigned sequentially or rely on the matching of `printf` params with positions in the cmd-line?  As far as padding goes, the O.P. can also use `printf "%012.3f"` formatting options to achieve some semblance of uniformity (maybe ;-) ). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks. But I want each iters run in same thread. For example, $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe) must be run in same thread, The next iterations will be another thread

Comment: maybe `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(./my_exe &) $(./my_exe &) $(./my_exe &) ; wait` will keep things in thread order. `wait` pauses script execution until all background jobs are completed. Good luck.